# Step of the text box -1 after the length of the specific lines

Tags: vb.net

I have these numbers:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And this VB code:

```
Dim lengthOfX As Integer = TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines.Length
Dim StartIndex = lengthOfX - 1
For i = StartIndex To 1 Step -1
```

It will go from the bottom up (i.e. from 5 to 1).
This code works from last to first.
How do I make it say it goes from 4 to 1 or from 3 to 1?

Comment: This is basic knowledge. Please refer to the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 to 1:

```
Dim lengthOfX As Integer = TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines.Length - 1
Dim StartIndex = lengthOfX - 1
For i = StartIndex To 1 Step -1
```

3 to 1:

```
Dim lengthOfX As Integer = TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines.Length - 2
Dim StartIndex = lengthOfX - 1
For i = StartIndex To 1 Step -1
```